# Setting up wake on lan on my NUC

Tags: wake-on-lan, openelec

I have Intel NUC i5 with Latest OpenElec installed on it.

I would like to wake it up from suspend using Wake On Lan feature (sent from another device on my home network), but I am having difficulties with that.

I have verified WOL is enabled in the BIOS, and I have tried to use the WOL Windows GUI provided in Depicious web site - www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-gui

I have put those values in the GUI:

MAC address of the NUC

Internet address - I tried both my router IP and my NUC internal IP

Subnet mask - I've put the mask I found in the OpenElec network screen

Port - I tried ports 7 and 9.

I have also tried to configure my router (DLink) to forward port 7 to the broadcast address (10.0.0.255) - but it doesn't allow configuring port forwarding (or virtual server as it is called) to that address.

Anything I am missing? Would really appreciate help here.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the IP addresses, and subnet masks, of the device you're trying to connect to, and from?  (As long as the IP addresses start with "10.",  you're not really causing security risks by posting that, since your ISP should block all untranslated traffic involving addresses that start with "10.")

Comment: The target device local IP is 10.0.0.2 (static DHCP lease), it is connected by wire to the router (10.0.0.138). I tried sending it magic WOL packets from laptop connected by wireless to the router. Laptop IP is 10.0.0.3. Subnet mask is 255.255.255.0.

Comment: First step in solving this would be to verify if your NUC is receiving the packets in the first place. Turn it on, run something like wireshark or tcpdump and monitor.

Comment: I am running OpenElec on the NUC, any idea which tool supported by this OS I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Pretty sure tcpdump should be available on just about any Linux distribution

Comment: OK, so there is an addon that adds tcpdump. I don't see any WOL packet received. I am using Depecious Windows GUI, I tried to send packet to the local IP and also tried to the external (router) IP with port 7 forwarded to the NUC local IP - nothing worked. So seems like the problem is I can't direct the WOL packet to the NUC ?

Comment: Try sending it from a wired device or the router itself. I have a feeling wireless does some funny business to WoL packets.

Comment: How can I send it from the router itself?

Answer (score 0):

If the D-Link supports any VPN functionality you could use that to tunnel IP broadcast traffic from your laptop to your local network.  If it doesn't support VPN connection itself, you could use another device inside your local network (a raspberry pi, for example) as a VPN server through which you could tunnel the required traffic.  SSH local tunnelling works nicely for this purpose, and is easy to configure in NAT on your D-Link.

Comment: How do I check if the router support VPN? I didn't find explicit VPN settings in its admin menus...
And isn't there any other way? Isn't there any way to send the WOL packet directly to the NUC, not through broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

If there is ddwrt support for your D-link then you can ad a static arp entry in the "startup command section" under "commands". You would enter something like : "arp -i br0 -s 192.168.1.254 FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF" without the quotes. and change the ip to something that fits your needs. after you added the command you can setup port forwarding like so : "9 - 192.168.1.254 - 9" again you need to change the ip to match the same ip as in your static arp entry and the standard ports for wol are 9 or 7.

The reason wol doesn't work over internet is because wol sends out broadcast frames and Firewalls are hardcoded to block this on the WAN side of it. eg: modem/router on port .255.

The instructions i gave you above provides a way to bypass this.
instead of your broadcastframe being send out to .255 and automatically being blocked by your modem/router. the broadcastframe is instead directed to .254 and that port is not blocked by your modem/router when you enable portforwarding.

Make sure that ddwrt is the first thing that connects to the WAN. NO double NAT or anything else that blocks ddwrt from being the first device to hit the internet.